# cURL/WGET triggers error 500, browser works fine

Tags: curl, wget

I'm facing this issue for several weeks now but i cannot find the solution myself.
When i use a webbrowser to go to https://insolventies.rechtspraak.nl/Services/VerslagenService/getPdf/01_obr_18_65_F_V_02 it shows the document just fine, when i use cURL or WGET it gives me a HTTP/500 error. Tried different machines, CentOS, Debian, Windows and MacOS but none of them seem to work. I tried using the commandline, php and asp.net but still no luck. It seems to me that using something other then a webbrowser isn't working, spoofing the useragent also wont work. I also tried contacting the server admin but they aren't willing to provide any details from their logfiles.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: you're probably missing some headers or using wrong content type, access it from browser, launch browser's developer tools , go to network and see what headers does the browser send

Comment: anyway the website should have given you 4xx status code instead of 500 internal server error

Comment: Cookie: X-CSRF-Token=7OqvnfwSephL/hMOxAxk5G4ji8BwQRacGjQpk/zHLlD1tviIIcFiRUrETorUMNuYGCUiT6B0dBVQYlqsrQ0cCsJkPGH1i2wtCQmds1UDncw=

Comment: the above is a cookie contaning some CSRF token which can only be got by a previous request to some url

Answer (score 0):

Adding the headers in cURL worked!

Sample:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://insolventies.rechtspraak.nl/Services/VerslagenService/getPdf/01_obr_18_65_F_V_02");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Connection:keep-alive',
'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1',
'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```